# Transactional Replication - Issue in Availablity Group

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We have 3 Node SQL Server Cluster (Always On availability group).

I wanted to implement Transactional Replication on 3rd Node which is configured as Asynchronous.

When I tried to create Publisher, initally I got error:

```
This database is not enabled for publication.
Unable to execute procedure. The database is not published. Execute the procedure in a database that is published for replication.
Changed database context to 'prod'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

Then I tried to add the database for Publication using following command.

```
USE prod
EXEC sp_replicationdboption @dbname = 'prod',
@optname = 'publish',
@value = 'true'
GO
```

I got another error:

```
Msg 3906, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sys.sp_MSdrop_pub_tables, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
Failed to update database "prod" because the database is read-only.
```

The above error was surprising, since I can see in the Database options that Read Only option is False.

[image]

Then I tried to fix the update issue using following commands:

```
USE prod GO
ALTER DATABASE [prod] SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT
GO
```

and now I am facing error:

```
Msg 1468, Level 16, State 3, Line 9
The operation cannot be performed on database "prod" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

I tried on Node 2 for 'prod' Database Publication there I got the following error:

```
Msg 976, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
The target database, 'prod', is participating in an availability group and is currently not accessible for queries.
Either data movement is suspended or the availability replica is not enabled for read access. 
To allow read-only access to this and other databases in the availability group, enable read access to one or more secondary availability replicas in the group.  
For more information, see the ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP statement in SQL Server Books Online.
```

Following is my cluster configuration:
[image]

What steps or configuration I will have to make in order to enable Transactional Replication on Node 3 or Node 2?

What I am doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: You cannot create publication on read replica. You can only do it on Primary which is Read-Write.

Comment: Are you aware of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) that specifies how to configure replication for a database that is participating in an AG?

Comment: @BenThul I do went through the documentation, but I performed all the steps in studio using the UI options available.

Comment: As @GAURAVRATHOD mentioned, you need to do that work against the primary replica in the AG. Why? The error message tells you that you're trying to make modifications against a read-only copy of the database.

Comment: @BenThul My primary database is already overloaded with operations, that's why I tried to do the replication on secondary instance to off load the replication activity. I think I will have to see some other approach.

Comment: @GAURAVRATHOD Please put your comments in answer section, so that I can accept it.

Comment: Presumably setting up replication will allow you to move some of the workload off of your primary though? Either way, as long as the distribution database is not colocated with your primary database, replication _shouldn't_ put too much strain on your database. I'd encourage you to try it and have a rapid backout plan ready in case the replication load does prove to be too much for your primary server to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create publication on read replica. You can only do it on Primary which is Read-Write.